# How can I get scons to not fail-fast with multiple targets?

Tags: python, scons

When scons is configured with multiple targets (e.g. build, static analysis, unit tests), if the static analysis fails then the unit tests don't run.

The builders run the relevant command using subprocess, then check the processes return code, and if non-zero, raises a `BuildError` exception.

How can I get scons to build every target and not fail-fast if one of the first targets fail?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this from the command line is to use the --keep or -k flag:

```
scons -k
```

SCons does not let you change this with the SetOption function.